# How to pass multiple array in get api without creating class object c#

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, get

I'm trying to pass multiple arrays from one project to another api project in c#.

Here is my method of calling project -

```
public DataTable GetDataTableForDocument(string ListType, string TableName, string[] DataColumn, string[] DataParam, string[] RequiredColumn)
    {
        DataTable lstTable = new DataTable();
        var baseAddress = "Base";
        using (HttpClient client = LocalUtility.InitializeHttpClient(baseAddress))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "/GetDataTableForDocument?ListType=" + ListType + "&TableName=" + TableName + "&DataColumn=" + DataColumn + "&DataParam=" + DataParam + "&RequiredColumn=" + RequiredColumn).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                lstTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(data);
            }
        }
        return lstTable;
    }
```

And here is my method of api project -

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Base/GetDataTableForDocument")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetDataTableForDocument(string ListType, string TableName, string[] DataColumn, string[] DataParam, string[] RequiredColumn)
    {
        return Ok(_repository.GetDataTableForDocument(ListType, TableName, DataColumn, DataParam, RequiredColumn));
    }
```

I'm getting error 500. Internal Server Error by this code.
This is the url made for Get Request - 
**http://localhost:60021/api/Base/GetDataTableForDocument?ListType=Distinct&TableName=PurchaseRequest&DataColumn=System.String[]&DataParam=System.String[]&RequiredColumn=System.String[]**

My Request Call is -
[image: Error Description]

Is it possible to get those arrays as parameters? If yes, how? If no, why? Also I don't want to create a class and pass it's object. 
I've searches the internet for a while now but nothing relevant comes up.

Comment: You don't want to instantiate an object? Or you don't want a static class? You should add some details as to what exactly your problem is, and what you've tried. Otherwise, this feels like an incomplete question to which you won't get (likely) great answers.

Comment: Thanks @AustinTFrench. I don't want to pass object in api. My problem is my API gives response of Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing ListType as a query parameter in your client, but in the controller action you have marked it to be resolved `[FromBody]`. First things first, remove this attribute from the action.

That was only the start. For your parameters which are arrays of string, a common solution is to construct a comma separated string with `string.Join(",",DataColumn)` (or another character, if your string contains commas) and on the controller you can separate them again with `DataColumn.Split(",")`.

Have you tried debugging the API and check step by step where the error is thrown?

By the way, 505 is not `Internal Server Error`. I doubt it's 505 (`Version not supported`).
Also, avoid the `.Result` in your HttpClient call. Try to declare this method as `async` and use the `.GetAsync()` properly, with an `await` keyword before it.

Comment: Thanks @Sotiris. I have made some mistake while copying code. First I had already removed [FromBody] second the code was 500 not 505. My other requests are working fine using .result in HttpClient Call. I didn't get however your string.join part. will look into it. edited my qestion.

Answer (score -1):

In General it is possible but it is a terrible idea,
something like:

[clickMe](https://medium.com/raml-api/arrays-in-query-params-33189628fa68)
or

you could go via [jsonApi](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets)

But in general I have to say that this is an awful idea. The [DTO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) fits great into most RestAPIs and has huge advantages in the long run: easier to extend, cleaner (= better to read & understand), smarter errorhandling,..

Comment: If you provide links with additional info, you should briefly summarize the part that is relevant for the question. Links may expire and your answer will not help anymore.